# SAP BAPI Transaction is not committing from WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, saprfc

From my WCF Service, I need to create a purchase order in SAP system and it's creating. But when I tried to commit the transaction it's not effecting in SAP system.

I am getting PONumber from SAP and it's not committing.

Can any one help me on this issue.

Here is my code:

```
NFCLMasters.ZMASTERDATA zmobj = new NFCLMasters.ZMASTERDATA();
            NFCLMasters.ZMASTERDATAResponse zmresponse = new NFCLMasters.ZMASTERDATAResponse();
            NFCLMasters.ZSM_WH_MST[] zmwarehousemaster = new NFCLMasters.ZSM_WH_MST[10];
            NFCLMasters.zws_mst mst = new NFCLMasters.zws_mst();
            zmobj.IWHMST = "X";
            zmobj.WHMST_LINES = zmwarehousemaster;
            zmresponse = mst.ZMASTERDATA(zmobj);

            NFCLTransactions.BAPI_PO_CREATE1 Zpo = new NFCLTransactions.BAPI_PO_CREATE1();
            NFCLTransactions.BAPI_PO_CREATE1Response Zporesponse = new NFCLTransactions.BAPI_PO_CREATE1Response();
            NFCLTransactions.zws_lo SapTrasactions = new NFCLTransactions.zws_lo ();
            // Data objects
            NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOHEADER poheader = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOHEADER();
            NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOHEADERX poheaderx = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOHEADERX();
            NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOITEM[] poitem = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOITEM[1];
            NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOITEMX[] poitemx = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOITEMX[1];
            NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOSCHEDULE[] poschedule = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOSCHEDULE[1];
            NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOSCHEDULX[] poschedulex = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOSCHEDULX[1];
            NFCLTransactions.BAPIITEMSHIP[] poitemship = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIITEMSHIP[1];
            NFCLTransactions.BAPIITEMSHIPX[] poitemshipx = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIITEMSHIPX[1];
            NFCLTransactions.BAPIRET2[] Bapireturn = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIRET2[100];                

            // ASSIGNING VALUES TO EACH OBJECT AND ADDING MAIN BAPI
            poheader.COMP_CODE = "NFCL"; poheader.DOC_TYPE = "ZPPS"; poheader.PURCH_ORG = "MKTG"; poheader.PUR_GROUP = "M13"; poheader.DOC_DATE = "2015-02-06";
            poheader.SUPPL_PLNT = "1311"; poheader.OUR_REF = "R006";
            Zpo.POHEADER = poheader;

            poheaderx.COMP_CODE = "X"; poheaderx.DOC_TYPE = "X"; poheaderx.PMNTTRMS = "X"; poheaderx.PURCH_ORG = "X"; poheaderx.PUR_GROUP = "X";
            poheaderx.SUPPL_PLNT = "X"; poheaderx.OUR_REF = "X";
            Zpo.POHEADERX = poheaderx;

            poitem[0] = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOITEM();
            poitem[0].PO_ITEM = "00001"; poitem[0].MATERIAL = "U01016501F"; poitem[0].PLANT = "1311"; poitem[0].STGE_LOC = "K038"; poitem[0].QUANTITY = 10;
            poitem[0].PERIOD_IND_EXPIRATION_DATE = "D"; 
            Zpo.POITEM = poitem;

            poitemx[0] = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOITEMX();
            poitemx[0].PO_ITEM = "00001"; poitemx[0].MATERIAL = "X"; poitemx[0].PLANT = "X"; poitemx[0].STGE_LOC = "X"; poitemx[0].QUANTITY = "X";
            poitemx[0].VAL_TYPE = "X"; poitemx[0].BATCH = "X";
            Zpo.POITEMX = poitemx;        

            poschedule[0] = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOSCHEDULE();
            poschedule[0].PO_ITEM = "00001"; poschedule[0].DELIVERY_DATE = "06.02.2015"; poschedule[0].QUANTITY = 10; 
            //poschedule[0].DELIV_TIME = 'X';
          // poschedule[0].GR_END_TIME
            Zpo.POSCHEDULE = poschedule;

            poschedulex[0] = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIMEPOSCHEDULX();
            poschedulex[0].PO_ITEM = "00001"; poschedulex[0].PO_ITEMX = "X"; poschedulex[0].DELIVERY_DATE = "X"; poschedulex[0].QUANTITY = "X";                
            Zpo.POSCHEDULEX = poschedulex;                       
            
            poitemship[0] = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIITEMSHIP();
            poitemship[0].PO_ITEM = "00001"; poitemship[0].SHIP_POINT = "R006";
            Zpo.POSHIPPING = poitemship;

            poitemshipx[0] = new NFCLTransactions.BAPIITEMSHIPX();
            poitemshipx[0].PO_ITEM = "00001"; poitemshipx[0].SHIP_POINT = "X";
            Zpo.POSHIPPINGX = poitemshipx;
            Zpo.RETURN = Bapireturn;

            NFCLTransactions.BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT transcommit = new NFCLTransactions.BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT();
            transcommit.WAIT = "X";
           Zporesponse = SapTrasactions.BAPI_PO_CREATE1(Zpo);
           response = Zporesponse.EXPPURCHASEORDER;
           NFCLTransactions.BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMITResponse resp =   SapTrasactions.BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT(transcommit);
```

Answer (score 6):

Your two BAPI calls are currently executed in individual contexts. Therefore the second call to BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT won't work because the second call context doesn't know anything about the results from the first call. You need to execute both calls within the same context. I don't know how to do that with the old, deprecated SAP .Net Connector, but with the current SAP Nco 3 you can achive it by using the methods `RfcSessionManager.BeginContext()` and `RfcSessionManager.EndContext()`.

If the BAPIs are only exposed as web services, a commit probably won't succeed because all calls to those web services are executed in their own context, so you have the same problem again. A workaround for using web services and `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT` would be to create a custom function module in the SAP system that first calls your BAPI and if that call succeeds, calls `BAPI_TRANSACTION_COMMIT`. That function module would have to be RFC capable and could be exposed as a web service for you. The parameters for that custom function module would (at least) be the same as for the BAPI you need, maybe an additional "COMMIT" parameter to allow you calling it without committing anything. Creating such a function module is relatively easy and shouldn't be a problem for a company familiar with SAP ERP.

Comment: Thank you Dirik, Now understood the problem. But If we use SAP.Net Connector then we need to connect to SAP System directly. But Client given only WSDL's for me. So I just added service reference to my project. I can able to get the data and pushing the data to SAP but the only problem is with BAPI transaction. I am new to WCF. can u give a me sample code to commit the BAPI transaction. your suggestions will help me in this scenario. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that is going to work as you hope. Web service calls are probably always executed in their own context. The company you work for will have to provide you with a custom RFC capable function module that calls both BAPIs in one session. That function module can then be exposed as a web service for you. A thread about the same topic at the SAP forums: http://scn.sap.com/message/6324213#6324213